# jquery delegate() events (mouseover mouseout) fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, hover

i have the following script firing mouseover and mouseout always twice! 
what do you suggest i do wrong (unbind, return e.g.)? i tried a few things but
nothing helped.

here is the code:

```
  $('#container').delegate('div.showmenu', 'mouseover mouseenter mouseout mouseleave', function(e){
  if (e.type === 'mouseover' || e.type==='mouseenter') { //jIE requires mouseenter, does not fire mouseover                                 
        if($(this).parents().closest('div').hasClass('whatever')){            
          alert(e.type);  //double-alerts mouseover

          menu.show();

    foldercmenu.hover(
        function(){
            $(this).show();                             
        },
        function(){
            $(this).hide();                                             
        }
    );                              

        }else {
    //do other stuff :-)
    }                                               
  }else if(e.type==='mouseout' || e.type==='mouseleave'){  //IE requires mouseleave, does not fire mouseout  
        alert(e.type);  //double-alerts mouseout
        menu.hide();
        $(this).unbind('mouseover mouseenter mouseout mouseleave');
  }
  //return false;   
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`mouseover` and `mouseout` a triggered when you enter/leave a child of the element, maybe that's the effect you are seeing.

An other problem is that you are binding the handler to both, `mouseover` **and** `mouseenter` ( and `mouseleave` and `mouseout`).

Only bind to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. jQuery is already taking care of the browser differences.

Comment: This is a poorly documented event issue...  Thanks for mentioning it. Took me a really long time to find this.  In my situation, the behaviour you suggest (mouseover & mouseout firing again when you enter/leave child nodes) is only occuring in IE<10 - all modern browsers seem to understand that I'm only interested in handling an event for the provided element, and not for all its children.  Even stopPropagation/ stopImmediatePropagation didn't affect this for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had something similar with .delegate();

Have you checked out http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/?

It fixed my issue.